# posting on FB using FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder fails

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk

I am tring to post on FB an Open Graph action using the code below. The Native share dialog is displayed correctly, with the title, url and image set. However when I tap button to post on FB, I am getting a "**Something went wrong. Please try again**" toast message, with the **"com.facebook.FecebookException: Error publishing message"** in the log. Nothing else to say what is wrong. Re-trying to publish, publishes on FB timeline an empty entry with no Open Graph action, no title, link, pic.  Please help.

```
    if (canPresentFBShareDialog) {
        // User obj
        OpenGraphObject session = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("beyondtimer:complete");
        session.setProperty("title", getFBPostString());
        session.setProperty("image", "https://scontent-a-ord.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/1017293_406347859487380_187920371_n.png");
        session.setProperty("url", "https://www.facebook.com/BeyondTimer");
        OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
        action.setProperty("session", session);

        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action,
                "beyondtimer:complete", "session")
                .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

    }
```

Comment: Ok, I got the createForPost("beyondtimer:complete") wrong. It should be the object name here,  "beyondtimer:session", not the action. It is working now

Comment: I am having a similar problem, I have seen what works for you except it does not "always" work for me. I can not create the dialog until I actually put the og object url in the Facebook object debugger (which it always scrapes fine with no errors). Then everything works! Weird right?

Comment: Hi @calinL I have executed your code and it was opening a dialog but it is dismissing automatically .. Is there any setting which i need to set ?

Comment: @calinL I am similarly having issues with this as well.  I don't feel that there is enough out there to guide me in the Facebook segment.  Lots of text and description in there on their site, but doesn't talk about all the fine details.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action,
                "beyondtimer:complete", "session") is depreciated, remove the "beyondtime:complete"?

Comment: Hi even after doing what you have suggested I am getting `com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to generate preview for user` this exception . What could be the reason ?

Comment: I don't know sorry, I ended up using a plug in called SimpleFacebook by sromku which has allowed me to share pictures with custom text. Give it a search!